# Ajax ResponseText with If statement

Tags: ajax

I am using Ajax to modify some data in a mysql database via a php file. I have written the code so that the php file echoes "OK" or "ERROR". I've checked with alert(ret) and it's working fine. But the problem is with the if (ret=="OK"). It's not getting inside this statement. Can anybody help me out?

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
       document.getElementById('Store_cards_action_form_close').click();
       ret = xmlhttp.responseText;
       if (ret=="OK"){
           alert("Congratulations. Transaction Successful.");
           document.location.reload();      
       }
       else{
           alert("You have Insufficient Coins to buy this Card!");
       }
   }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","script_card_transaction.php?" + para,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: You probably have some whitespace around the text in your response. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you probably have some whitespace characters around your response text. You could [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) the response text or instead, work with a JSON formatted string. For example, in your PHP file

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('status' => $status)); // where $status is 'OK' or 'ERROR'
exit;
```

Then, parse this as JSON in your JS

```
var ret = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
if (ret.status == 'OK') {
    // etc
```

I would probably go a bit further and use something less ambiguous than the strings "OK" and "ERROR". For example

```
echo json_encode(array('success' => $isSuccess)); // where $isSuccess is a boolean (true or false)
```

and the JS...

```
if (ret.success) {
    // etc
```

Comment: Thanks for the json advice. There was no whitespace I checked. But anyway problem was solved with the jsonencode. Still the why it's not working with simple string instead of json is bothering me. Thank a lot mate.

Comment: @Draven Could have been a carriage return or any other invisible character in your response text. Whatever it was, it was not equal to "OK"